# Bash - How to format file?

Tags: linux, bash

I have a large file called `aliase.txt`, and this files contains a list of some alias. They have this syntx: `Alias  "Aliasname" = 1, 2, 3`.

But sometimes they have the syntax:

```
Alias  "Aliasname" = 1, 2, 3 \
      4, 5, 6
```

Sometimes it has more than one new line, and there are more Backslash. but these are also offset by 10 spaces.
(The new line is always offset by 10 spaces.)

I need to get rid of the backslash and the "return", so that it would look like this: `Alias  "Aliasname" = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6`. In the End this should become a new file, I can send to someone.

After that I am supposed to format the file even more, so that in the End, it would look like this:

```
Aliasname      1
Aliasname      2
Aliasname      3
Aliasname      4
Aliasname      5
Aliasname      6
Aliasname2      1
Aliasname2      2
Aliasname2      3
```

But this is not the only content in the file, there are some other alias too. For example: `H_Alias` or `Port_Alias`. But these are not important for me, I only need to filter out the alias: `Alias`. I already filtered out comments and Blank Spaces.

Is there a way this is possible, and if there is, could someone please help me with it.

Kind Regards Elias

Comment: These have the literal string `\"Return"` in them? If not, fix the formatting of your question to show the actual format instead of trying to describe it.

Comment: @Shawn  I have changed it, are xou able to answer the question now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your file actually looks like this:

```
Alias "Aliasname1" = 1, 2, 3
Alias "Aliasname2" = 4, 5, 6 \
          7, 8, 9
Alias "Aliasname3" = a, b, c
```

you can join the continued lines with:

```bash
sed '/\\$/{N; s/\\\n[[:space:]]\{10\}/, /}' aliase.txt
Alias "Aliasname1" = 1, 2, 3
Alias "Aliasname2" = 4, 5, 6 , 7, 8, 9
Alias "Aliasname3" = a, b, c
```

(If a line ends in a backslash, read the next line of input and append it to the pattern space, then replace the sequence "backslash, newline, and 10 more whitespace characters" with a comma)

Comment: No, it does not look excactly look like that. There are somw other lines in it too, mostly some other alias. Can I search for only one specific type of Alias in the file? That would be `Alias`, but there are some others to, for example `H_Alias` or `Port_Alias`.

Comment: @Elias Your sample input should be representative of your real input and definitely include any edge cases that have to be dealt with.

Comment: OK, I will add this into the question.

Comment: Hello, I now did following: 
```
cat aliase.txt | grep -v ^# | grep -v ^$   >> lines.txt
cat lines.txt | sed '/\\$/{N; s/\\\n[[:space:]]\{10\}/, /}' >> test.txt
cat test.txt | grep "Alias" >> new_aliase.txt
```

So I was able to implementy your code pretty well. So thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Given an `aliase.txt` like this:

```
Port_Alias "Aliasname1"  = 11, 12, 13
Alias  "Aliasname2" = 21, 22, 23 \
          24, 25, 26
Alias  "Aliasname3" = 31
H_Alias  "Aliasname4" = 41, 42, 43 \
          44, 45, 46
Alias  "Aliasname5" = \
51 \
    52 \
        53
  Alias "Aliasname6"=61
```

The following `awk` program:

```bash
awk '
    $1 == "Alias" {
         while (sub(/\\$/,""))
             getline $(NF+1)
         gsub(/[ ,"=]+/," ")
         for (i = 3; i <= NF; i++)
             print $2, $i
    }
' aliase.txt
```

Will yield:

```
Aliasname2 21
Aliasname2 22
Aliasname2 23
Aliasname2 24
Aliasname2 25
Aliasname2 26
Aliasname3 31
Aliasname5 51
Aliasname5 52
Aliasname5 53
Aliasname6 61
```

Comment: Hi, I tried to use this, but it didn´t work for me, because there are also different Alias.

Comment: What do you mean by different Aliases? It's crucial that you provide a comprehensive sample of your input data; The possible solutions depend on the smallest details...

Comment: Its pretty hard to explain, but thanks for your help.

Comment: I updated my answer; as you can see in my example, it handles a few possible border cases, but I can't be sure that it's correct tho. Are all your aliases single words? can the values contain spaces? etc...

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> echo "${input…}" | 
>
> mawk  NF=NF  RS='(\\?(\r?\n)+)?(H_|Port_|)Alias |\\?\n+'\
>      OFS='|' FS='[^[:alnum:]]+'
> ```

```
|Aliasname1|11|12|13|
|Aliasname2|21|22|23|24|25|26|
|Aliasname3|31|
|Aliasname4|41|42|43|44|
```

From here on it should be mostly trivial regarding the final formatting.

Maybe these staircases would help :

> ```
> mawk '(OFS="\f\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b"$(++_+_)" "\
>        )^!(NF-=_*($++_=$--_=_="")^_)' \
>    ORS= \
>     FS='[^[:alnum:]]+' OFS= RS='(\\?(\r?\n)+)?(H_|Port_|)Alias |\\?\n+'
> ```

```
Aliasname1 
Aliasname1 11
 Aliasname1 12
  Aliasname1 13
   Aliasname2 
  Aliasname2 21
   Aliasname2 22
    Aliasname2 23
     Aliasname2 24
      Aliasname2 25
       Aliasname2 26
        Aliasname3 
       Aliasname3 31
        Aliasname4 
       Aliasname4 41
        Aliasname4 42
         Aliasname4 43
          Aliasname4 44
```

Comment: Hi, what is `mawk` supposed to be?

Comment: @Elias : just a different engine for `awk`, similar to `gnu gawk` - fewer bells and whistles, but ****much***** faster

Comment: OK, I tried it, but `mawk` was not found. But thanks for your help. Kind regards Elias

Comment: @Elias : then use `gawk` and run the same code